# How to iterate rows with known start position and mixed column ordering, exactly as if walking the corresponding index?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a given, unmodifiable table design which resembles:

```sql
create table t (
   c1  varchar(64) not null,
   c2  bigint not null
   -- some more columns which are not relevant here
);
-- The primary key, intentionally not (also) modeled as a constraint.
create unique index on t(c1 asc, c2 desc);
```

I simply want to iterate rows from this table in the order `c1 asc, c2 desc`, starting at a known position, e.g., `('foo', 5)`. The query must be efficient, i.e. the query planner must be able to take advantage of the unique index and do an index scan if the table is large enough. This should require at most `log(n) + 2 * limit` reads for large tables.

Examples (fixed after edit):

```txt
- Given t contains ('a', 1), ('a', 2),
                   ('b', 1), ('b', 3), 
                   ('c', 2), ('c', 17)

- When we query for ('', <any>) 
- Then we get t

- When we query for ('a', 2)
- Then we get ('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('b', 1), ('c', 17), ('c', 2)

- When we query for ('b', 1)
- Then we get ('c', 17), ('c', 2)

- When we query for ('c', 3)
- Then we get ('c', 2)

- When we query for ('q', <any>)
- Then we get the empty set
```

You'd think something like this should be trivial, but apparently with SQL this is harder than it should be!? Consider the
following *incorrect* (!) queries which I'm only listing to avoid getting them as an answer ;)

```sql
-- Incorrect: Ordering of row expression is inconsistent with ORDER BY clause.
select * from t where (t.c1, t.c2) > ('foo', 5) order by t.c1 asc, t.c2 desc limit 1000;

-- Incorrect: Ignores coupling between c2 and c1, skips rows that must be included.
select * from t where t.c1 > 'foo' and t.c2 > 5 order by t.c1 asc, t.c2 desc limit 1000;
```

Comment: _Incorrect_, does that mean wrong result, wrong result order, or exception?

Comment: *Incorrect* as in 'result doesn't contain exactly the expected rows'.

Comment: `select * from t where (t.c1, t.c2) > ('foo', 5) ..` complies with your  examples.  Could you provide an example when it fails?

Comment: @Serg You're right, I got the examples all wrong. I'll fix that section.

Comment: For a generic solution, you'd have to define custom operators and an operator class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the trickiest part will *stopping* it from using the index. Which is to say just walking the index from one end discarding stuff that doesn't match the filter.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (c1 = 'CXB' AND c2 <= 57) OR c1 > 'CXB'
ORDER BY c1 ASC, c2 DESC LIMIT 999;
```

The planner isn't smart enough (afaict in 2021) to spot that the `OR` there has a strong correlation on each side. We know that we are actually just trying to get a subset of the table, but the planner - nope.

So - one thing you can do with a tricky `OR` is to split it into two subqueries and use `UNION ALL`.

```
WITH part1 AS (
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (c1 = 'CXB' AND c2 <= 57)
  ORDER BY c1 ASC, c2 DESC LIMIT 999
), part2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE c1 > 'CXB'
  ORDER BY c1 ASC, c2 DESC LIMIT 999
)
SELECT * FROM part1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM part2
ORDER BY c1 ASC, c2 DESC LIMIT 999;
```

I've written this as a CTE (the `WITH` clauses) because I think it looks more readable that way. It should be identical to actual subqueries for the planner though.

That gives me (`EXPLAIN ANALYSE ...`) a plan something like:

```
 Limit  (cost=110.23..177.47 rows=999 width=16) (actual time=0.232..2.172 rows=999 loops=1)
   ->  Merge Append  (cost=110.23..181.31 rows=1056 width=16) (actual time=0.230..1.872 rows=999 loops=1)
         Sort Key: t1.c1, t1.c2 DESC
         ->  Sort  (cost=109.80..109.94 rows=57 width=16) (actual time=0.141..0.155 rows=57 loops=1)
               Sort Key: t1.c1, t1.c2 DESC
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..107.56 rows=57 width=16) (actual time=0.055..0.104 rows=57 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using t1u1 on t1  (cost=0.42..107.56 rows=57 width=16) (actual time=0.055..0.085 rows=57 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (((c1)::text = 'CXB'::text) AND (c2 <= 57))
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..50.81 rows=999 width=16) (actual time=0.085..1.403 rows=942 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using t1u1 on t1 t1_1  (cost=0.42..40347.24 rows=799950 width=16) (actual time=0.085..1.143 rows=942 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((c1)::text > 'CXB'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.677 ms
 Execution Time: 2.387 ms
```

You incur an extra sort I'm afraid, but you can't guarantee your ordering otherwise.

Obviously this doesn't give your your odd queries that should be returning true or an empty set. That's because they don't really make any sense in the sense of asking for a subset of the table.

Test data used for above query plan:

```
CREATE FUNCTION threechars(i int) RETURNS TEXT AS $$ SELECT chr((i / (26*26)) % 26 + 65) || chr((i / 26) % 26 + 65) || chr(i % 26 + 65) $$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE ;

CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 varchar(64) not null, c2 bigint not null, i int not null);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t1u1 ON t1 (c1 ASC, c2 DESC);

INSERT INTO t1 SELECT threechars(i / 99), 99 - (i % 99), i FROM generate_series(0, 999999) i;

ANALYSE t1;
```

Comment: Oh, it's as simple as `(c1=X and c2<y) or (c1>X)` and doing UNION ALL (or two queries). Why didn't I think of that... *thank you so much!* I don't really need a specific ordering for my use case. It would've been convenient if it came for free, but I'll gladly fetch X rows into memory and sort them client-side if that takes some load off the DB.

Comment: It shouldn't be an expensive sort - you are only talking about 1000 rows and they should be in the right order already.

Answer (score 2):

One hacky solution would switch the sign of the second column:

```
create unique index on t(c1 asc, (- c2) asc);
```

Then you can use:

```
select *
from t
where (t.c1, (- t.c2)) > ('foo', -5)
order by t.c1 asc, (- t.c2) asc
limit 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately my schema is sort of immutable. If I could change or add another index I'd probably end up just using `create unique index on t (c1, c2  and adjust my query. `